# Creating and send ipa with only Technical permission

Tags: ipa, ios-provisioning

I have developed an Application and verified in simulator.
Now i need to send build to my Client. My client has provided me technical role in Itunes connect .

I can login in Itunes connect with my ID and can see my name under users as technical permission.

Please let me know how to proceed to create an ipa .
I do have an IPhone wih me . My purpose is to create an Ipa. Install it in my Iphone and test and the provide build to client.

Any help will be greatly appreciated !!

-mia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out.
Normally its not the access we need in Itunes connect.

Client must provide member or admin access in developer account and then only we can create an ipa from our side with the provisioning profile and certificate at clients account.

Thanks
-mia